# cakephp unit testing models, fixtures problem

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, tdd, cakephp-1.2

So i'm working with CakePHP v1.2.5. On my current project, I decided to start writing tests as I code the functionality (yay TDD). I'm having trouble with fixture loading though.

To aid in the process, I'll describe my code (Really quite simple right now). My model is defined like so

```
// app/models/newsitem.php
<?php
class NewsItem extends AppModel
{
  var $name='NewsItem';
}
?>

// app/tests/fixtures/newsitem_fixture.php
<?php

class NewsItemFixture extends CakeTestFixture 
{
    var $name = 'NewsItem';
    var $import = 'NewsItem';

    var $records = array(
        array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'News Item 1', 'body' => 'This is the first piece of news', 'created' => '2007-03-18 10:39:23', 'modified' => '2007-03-18 10:41:31'),
        array('id' => '2', 'title' => 'News 2', 'body' => 'This is some other piece of news', 'created' => '2009-05-04 9:00:00', 'modified' => '2009-05-05 12:34:56')
    );
}

?>

// app/tests/models/newsitem.test.php
<?php
App::Import('Model', 'NewsItem');

class NewsItemTestCase extends CakeTestCase
{
    var $fixtures = array('app.newsitem');

    function setUp()
    {
        $this->NewsItem =& ClassRegistry::init('NewsItem');
    }

    function testFindAll()
    {
        $results = $this->NewsItem->findAll();
        $expected = array(
            array('NewsItem' => array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'News Item 1', 'body' => 'This is the first piece of news', 'created' => '2007-03-18 10:39:23', 'modified' => '2007-03-18 10:41:31')),
            array('NewsItem' => array('id' => '2', 'title' => 'News 2', 'body' => 'This is some other piece of news', 'created' => '2009-05-04 9:00:00', 'modified' => '2009-05-05 12:34:56'))
        );
        print_r($results);
        $this->assertEqual($results, $expected);
    }   
}

?>
```

Anyway, my problem is, when I run the test suite in a browser (going to http://localhost/test.php), the test case runner tries to load my app's layout (which is weird cuz I'm just testing the model) which references another model which is obviously not loaded in the test database and I get an error.

And if I remove the 
`var $fixtures = array('app.newsitem')` line from my NewsItemTestCase file, the test case runs properly, BUT it doesn't load the fixtures (for obvious reasons).

Any ideas, suggestions? To be honest I'm having a little trouble finding more than 3 tutorials on this matter.

Comment: Just a heads up. I seem to have solved the problem by re-baking the model and test classes using cake's bake console utility. Only change I see is that the model class is correctly (based on one's opinion) is now in app/models/news_item.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this was long ago but the issue is the naming conventions, if the fixture is called 'NewsItemFixture' the file should be news_item_fixture, not newsitem_fixture. if you want the file called newsitem_fixture the fixture class should be NewsitemFixture.

same goes for all other files, like the model you have there.

Comment: Sorry to dig this up, but I'm currently experiencing the same problem. I've updated my naming to meet convention, but still no luck. If you've got the time to look, I'd appreciate it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408936/cakephp-unit-testing-fixture-name-conventions-argh

Comment: An easy way to make sure your files are named correctly (including tests and fixtures) is to use the [BakeShell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html), although that's really 2.x and up.

Comment: Cakes bake has been around long before 2.x