# CakePHP Unit Testing Fixture Name Conventions Argh?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, model, naming-conventions, fixtures

I've been bashing my head against the wall trying to figure out why I can't get my fixture to load properly. When I attempt to run my test, my layout is rendered. If I comment out the fixture, the test runs properly. I've gone over this 100 times and I can't seem to see what's wrong.

Heres my Videosview.test.php

```
App::import('Model','Videosview');

class VideosviewTest extends Videosview {
    var $name = 'Videosview';
    //var $useDbConfig = 'test_suite';
}

class VideosviewTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
    var $fixtures = array( 'app.videosview' );

    function testIncrementTimer() {
        $this->autoLayout = $this->autoRender = false;

        $this->Videosview =& ClassRegistry::init('Videosview');
        //$video_view = $this->find('first');
        $result = $this->Videosview->increment_timer($video_view['Videosview']['video_id'],$video_view['Videosview']['user_id'],1);
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

This is my videosview_fixture.php

```
class VideosviewFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    var $name = 'Videosview';

    var $import = array('model' => 'Videosview', 'records' => true);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, we never did find an answer to this :-(
I've since been moved onto another project, so I won't be actively seeking an answer, but I would like to see one eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of strange code there, it looks like you don't understand how test are used. The problem doesn't come from your fixture import.

$this->assertTrue(true) will always return true. There is no need to declare VideosviewTest.

As I don't know what your increment_timer method is supposed to do I cannot write a test for it, but let's suppose it returns the value passed + 1:

```
function increment_timer($id = null){
    return $id++;
}
```

Your test case should be

```
App::import('Model', 'Videosview');

class VideosviewTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
    var $fixtures = array('app.videosview');

    function startTest() {
        $this->Videosview =& ClassRegistry::init('Videosview');
    }

    function endTest() {
        unset($this->Videosview);
        ClassRegistry::flush();
    }

    function testIncrementTimer() {
        $input = 1;

        // let's test increment_timer function by asserting true that return value is $input + 1, green bar
        $this->assertTrue( $this->Videosview->increment_timer($input) == ($input+1), 'Should return 2' );
        // let's test increment_timer function by asserting false that return value is $input + 2, green bar
        $this->assertFalse( $this->Videosview->increment_timer($input) == ($input+2), 'Should not return 3' );
        //the following returns an error as return value is not equal to $input + 2, Red bar
        $this->assertTrue( $this->Videosview->increment_timer($input) == ($input+2), 'Should return 2' );
    }
}
```

This is what you should get, and have expected

[image: Test screenshot]

Comment: I'm no longer on this project, or even with this company anymore, but this looks like a well written answer to what was a very difficult question. Thank you kaklon!